# Speed issues in a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm having a problem with a mysql query.

```
SELECT p.`id_product`, pl.`name`, p.`ean13`, p.`upc`, p.`active`, p.`reference`, m.`name` AS manufacturer_name, stock.`quantity`, product_shop.advanced_stock_management, p.`customizable` 
FROM `ps_product` p 
INNER JOIN ps_product_shop product_shop ON (product_shop.id_product = p.id_product AND product_shop.id_shop = 1) 
LEFT JOIN `ps_product_lang` `pl` ON p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product` AND pl.`id_lang` = 3 AND pl.id_shop = 1 
LEFT JOIN `ps_manufacturer` `m` ON m.`id_manufacturer` = p.`id_manufacturer` 
LEFT JOIN `ps_product_supplier` `sp` ON sp.`id_product` = p.`id_product` 
LEFT JOIN `ps_product_attribute` `pa` ON pa.`id_product` = p.`id_product` 
LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute_shop product_attribute_shop ON (product_attribute_shop.id_product_attribute = pa.id_product_attribute AND product_attribute_shop.id_shop = 1) 
LEFT JOIN ps_stock_available stock ON (stock.id_product = p.id_product AND stock.id_product_attribute = IFNULL(`pa`.id_product_attribute, 0) AND stock.id_shop = 1 AND stock.id_shop_group = 0 ) 
WHERE (
    pl.`name` LIKE '%search_word%' 
    OR p.`ean13` LIKE '%search_word%' 
    OR p.`upc` LIKE '%search_word%' 
    OR p.`reference` LIKE '%search_word%' 
    OR p.`supplier_reference` LIKE '%search_word%' 
    OR `product_supplier_reference` LIKE '%search_word%' 
    OR pa.`reference` LIKE '%search_word%' 
    OR pa.`supplier_reference` LIKE '%search_word%' 
    OR pa.`ean13` LIKE '%search_word%' 
    OR pa.`upc` LIKE '%search_word%'
) 
GROUP BY `id_product` 
ORDER BY pl.`name` ASC
```

This is a typical Prestashop query, executed by Product::searchByName().
I have two databases, one is a current database and the other one is a backup from a month ago.

The backup database has more rows than the current, because some products were deleted. There are around 8200 rows in the ps_product table of the backup DB, and around 6700 in the current DB.

And when I execute this query in the backup DB, the execution time it's 1 second, but when I execute it in the current DB... the execution time it's more than 300 seconds!!!

What's wrong with the current database? The execution time should be smaller!! I'm getting mad with this!!!

Comment: Are they running on the same server hardware? Perhaps the productive DB is already under heavy load?

Comment: Yes, they are running on the same machine, the developing server.

Comment: Do an EXPLAIN for the query, see what indexes it's using to execute

Comment: Try to unload/reload the database, probably it has some problems with file fragmentation or other cache settings

Comment: The database is recently imported from the production server, where this query it is slow too T_T

Comment: I did an EXPLAIN and I get different results, but I don't know how EXPLAIN works exactly :)

Comment: It's obvious, even without output of `EXPLAIN` that the query in question will perform full table scans (due to `LIKE '%search%'` condition in `WHERE` clause). However, you included the query but you haven't mentioned MySQL config at all. At such small amount of records, even full table scans should be super fast - this indicates your MySQL is not configured at all. What is the storage engine you are using and what are  the configuration settings? Have you allowed for sufficient RAM usage?

Comment: when deleting rows from a db table , you should be doing OPTIMIZE TABLE .. deleted rows still occupy some space

Comment: The Mysql config is not the point, because the production server it's a dedicated server and the mysql configuration it's fine. Other databases are working fine in this server. So... no that obvious. I think the problem seems to be that the table has been corrupted and it has not the indexes properly defined. Thank you very much Mark Baker!

Answer (score 1):

Please compare your old (backup) and new databases structures:

1. Tables **engine types** (InnoDB and MyISAM),
2. **Indexes** (including foreign keys, if engine type is InnoDB). If indexes exists, try remove them and create again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was missing indexes on some tables, that were corrupted.